# SNMP Agent in Python with custom MIB

Tags: python, pysnmp, mib

I implemented an SNMP agent in Python with the pysnmp library. This is the code that I used to respond to a custom OID.

```
from datetime import datetime
from pysnmp import debug
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import cmdrsp, context
from pysnmp.proto.api import v2c
from pysnmp.smi import builder, instrum, exval

# Uncomment this to turn pysnmp debugging on
#debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('all'))

formatting = '[%(asctime)s-%(levelname)s]-(%(module)s) %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=formatting, )

logging.info("Starting....")

# Create SNMP engine
snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine()

# Transport setup

# UDP over IPv4
config.addTransport(
    snmpEngine,
    udp.domainName,
    udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode(('0.0.0.0', 12345))
)

# SNMPv2c setup

# SecurityName <-> CommunityName mapping.
config.addV1System(snmpEngine, 'my-area', 'public')

# Allow read MIB access for this user / securityModels at VACM
# Limit access to just the custom MIB. Widen if need be
config.addVacmUser(snmpEngine,
                   2,
                   'my-area',
                   'noAuthNoPriv',
                   (1, 3, 6, 4),
                   (1, 3, 6, 4))


# Create an SNMP context and ensure the custom MIB is loaded
# Your system must have this MIB installed otherwise pysnmp
# can't load it!
snmpContext = context.SnmpContext(snmpEngine)
logging.debug('Loading __EXAMPLE-MIB module...'),
mibBuilder = snmpContext.getMibInstrum().getMibBuilder()
(MibTable,
 MibTableRow,
 MibTableColumn,
 MibScalarInstance) = mibBuilder.importSymbols(
    'SNMPv2-SMI',
    'MibTable',
    'MibTableRow',
    'MibTableColumn',
    'MibScalarInstance'
)
logging.debug('done')


RowStatus, = mibBuilder.importSymbols('SNMPv2-TC', 'RowStatus')

mibBuilder.exportSymbols(
    '__EXAMPLE-MIB',
    # table object
    exampleTable=MibTable((1, 3, 6, 4, 1)).setMaxAccess('readcreate'),
    # table row object, also carries references to table indices
    exampleTableEntry=MibTableRow((1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 5)).setMaxAccess('readcreate').setIndexNames((0, '__EXAMPLE-MIB', 'exampleTableColumn1')),
    # table column: string index
    exampleTableColumn1=MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 5, 1), v2c.OctetString()).setMaxAccess('readcreate'),
    # table column: string value
    exampleTableColumn2=MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 5, 2), v2c.OctetString()).setMaxAccess('readcreate'),
    # table column: integer value with default
    exampleTableColumn3=MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 5, 3), v2c.Integer32(123)).setMaxAccess('readcreate'),
    # table column: row status
    exampleTableStatus=MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 5, 4), RowStatus('notExists')).setMaxAccess('readcreate')
)
logging.debug('done')

(exampleTableEntry,
 exampleTableColumn2,
 exampleTableColumn3,
 exampleTableStatus) = mibBuilder.importSymbols(
    '__EXAMPLE-MIB',
    'exampleTableEntry',
    'exampleTableColumn2',
    'exampleTableColumn3',
    'exampleTableStatus'
)

rowInstanceId = exampleTableEntry.getInstIdFromIndices('example record one')
mibInstrumentation = snmpContext.getMibInstrum()
mibInstrumentation.writeVars(
    ((exampleTableColumn2.name + rowInstanceId, 'hello'),
     (exampleTableColumn3.name + rowInstanceId, 123456),
     (exampleTableStatus.name + rowInstanceId, 'createAndGo'))
)

logging.debug('done')
logging.debug('Snmp Agent Start')

# Register SNMP Applications at the SNMP engine for particular SNMP context
cmdrsp.GetCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)
cmdrsp.SetCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)
cmdrsp.NextCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)
cmdrsp.BulkCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)

# Register an imaginary never-ending job to keep I/O dispatcher running forever
snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)

# Run I/O dispatcher which would receive queries and send responses
try:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
except:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
    raise
```

I use the iReasoning MIB Browser to send an SNMP request.
When I send the *Get* request of **.1.3.6.4.1.5.1** oid, an error with this explanation appear: "**No access error.**"

Finally, I send *Get Subtree* request of **.1.3.6.4.1.5** oid and MIB Browser show this result below:

[image]

As you see, the OID result is:
**.1.3.6.4.1.5.1.18.101.120.97.109.112.108.101.32.114.101.99.111.114.100.32.111.110.101**

This is not short and have some added values.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you observe seems valid.

You can't operate on the `1.3.6.4.1.5.1` managed object because it's not a value object, but rather sort of a "type" defining the properties of the "variables" that can derive from it. The former is called *managed object*, the latter is *managed object instance* in SNMP.

To address particular managed object instance you need to append one or more sub-OIDs to the managed object OID. This trailing part is known as *managed object instance ID* in SNMP.

In your implementation, managed object instance ID is derived from the "example record one" string. It takes at least as many elements in the trailing part of the OID as there are characters in the string. That explains why the resulting OID is that long.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar question where it was necessary to use the integer "1" as an index as the table was indexed by IF-MIB ifIndex.

Discovered that this worked:  `rowInstanceId = (1,)`

The following shows the result of the script shown below:

```
cd ~
snmpwalk -v 3 -u usr-sha-aes -a SHA -A authkey1 -x aes -X privkey1 -l authPriv -L n -m all localhost 1
```

Output:

```
IEEE802dot11-MIB::dot11TransmittedFragmentCount.1 = Counter32: 123
IEEE802dot11-MIB::dot11GroupTransmittedFrameCount.1 = Counter32: 123456
IEEE802dot11-MIB::dot11FailedCount.1 = Counter32: 1350
IEEE802dot11-MIB::dot11RetryCount.1 = Counter32: 1251
IEEE802dot11-MIB::dot11MultipleRetryCount.1 = Counter32: 234
IEEE802dot11-MIB::dot11FrameDuplicateCount.1 = Counter32: 566
IEEE802dot11-MIB::dot11RTSSuccessCount.1 = Counter32: 867
IEEE802dot11-MIB::dot11RTSFailureCount.1 = Counter32: 231
IEEE802dot11-MIB::dot11AckFailureCount.1 = Counter32: 856
IEEE802dot11-MIB::dot11ReceivedFragmentCount.1 = Counter32: 568
IEEE802dot11-MIB::dot11GroupReceivedFrameCount.1 = Counter32: 34568
IEEE802dot11-MIB::dot11FCSErrorCount.1 = Counter32: 345
IEEE802dot11-MIB::dot11TransmittedFrameCount.1 = Counter32: 78567
IEEE802dot11-MIB::dot11WEPUndecryptableCount.1 = Counter32: 4545
RFC1213-MIB::ifDescr.1 = STRING: "wifi0"
RFC1213-MIB::ifDescr.1 = No more variables left in this MIB View (It is past the end of the MIB tree)
```

Here is the script:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pysnmp import debug
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import cmdrsp, context
from pysnmp.proto.api import v2c
from pysnmp.smi import builder, instrum, exval, error
from pysnmp.proto import rfc1902


# Create SNMP engine
# For the correct  SNMP Engine ID format please see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3411.html#page-41
# snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine()
snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine(rfc1902.OctetString(hexValue='8000000004030201'))

# Transport setup
# UDP over IPv4 and allow any IP address at port 161
config.addTransport(
    snmpEngine,
    udp.domainName,
    udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode(('0.0.0.0', 161))
)

# SNMPv2c setup
# SecurityName <-> CommunityName mapping. my-area username maps to the community name of public.
config.addV1System(snmpEngine, 'my-area', 'public')

# Allow readonly MIB access for this v2 user / securityModels at VACM
# Limit access to just the MIBs used here at VACM. Widen if need be
config.addVacmUser(snmpEngine, 2, 'my-area', 'noAuthNoPriv', (1, 2))
config.addVacmUser(snmpEngine, 2, 'my-area', 'noAuthNoPriv', (1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2))

# SNMPv3/USM setup
# user: usr-sha-des, auth: SHA, priv AES128
config.addV3User(
    snmpEngine, 'usr-sha-aes',
    config.usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol, 'authkey1',
    config.usmAesCfb128Protocol, 'privkey1'
)
# Limit readonly access to just the MIBs used here at VACM for the v3 user.  Widen if need be.
config.addVacmUser(snmpEngine, 3, 'usr-sha-aes', 'authPriv', (1, 2))
config.addVacmUser(snmpEngine, 3, 'usr-sha-aes', 'authPriv', (1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2))

# Create an SNMP context
snmpContext = context.SnmpContext(snmpEngine)

mibBuilder = snmpContext.getMibInstrum().getMibBuilder()
(MibTable,
 MibTableRow,
 MibTableColumn,
 MibScalarInstance) = mibBuilder.importSymbols(
    'SNMPv2-SMI',
    'MibTable',
    'MibTableRow',
    'MibTableColumn',
    'MibScalarInstance'
)

mibBuilder.exportSymbols(
    'IF-MIB',
    ifTable=MibTable((1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2), ).setMaxAccess('notaccessible'),
    ifEntry=MibTableRow((1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1)).setMaxAccess('notaccessible').setIndexNames((0, 'IF-MIB', 'ifIndex')),
    ifIndex=MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1), v2c.Integer32()).setMaxAccess('notaccessible'),
    ifDescr=MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2), v2c.OctetString()).setMaxAccess('readonly')
)


# All WiFi products use the ifIndex of 1 for the WLAN interface.

mibBuilder.exportSymbols(
    'IEEE802dot11-MIB',
    dot11CountersTable=MibTable((1, 2, 840, 10036, 2, 2), ).setMaxAccess('notaccessible'),
    dot11CountersEntry=MibTableRow((1, 2, 840, 10036, 2, 2, 1)).setMaxAccess('notaccessible').setIndexNames((0, 'IF-MIB', 'ifIndex')),
    dot11TransmittedFragmentCount=MibTableColumn((1, 2, 840, 10036, 2, 2, 1, 1), v2c.Counter32()).setMaxAccess('readonly'),
    dot11GroupTransmittedFrameCount=MibTableColumn((1, 2, 840, 10036, 2, 2, 1, 2), v2c.Counter32()).setMaxAccess('readonly'),
    dot11FailedCount=MibTableColumn((1, 2, 840, 10036, 2, 2, 1, 3), v2c.Counter32()).setMaxAccess('readonly'),
    dot11RetryCount=MibTableColumn((1, 2, 840, 10036, 2, 2, 1, 4), v2c.Counter32()).setMaxAccess('readonly'),
    dot11MultipleRetryCount=MibTableColumn((1, 2, 840, 10036, 2, 2, 1, 5), v2c.Counter32()).setMaxAccess('readonly'),
    dot11FrameDuplicateCount=MibTableColumn((1, 2, 840, 10036, 2, 2, 1, 6), v2c.Counter32()).setMaxAccess('readonly'),
    dot11RTSSuccessCount=MibTableColumn((1, 2, 840, 10036, 2, 2, 1, 7), v2c.Counter32()).setMaxAccess('readonly'),
    dot11RTSFailureCount=MibTableColumn((1, 2, 840, 10036, 2, 2, 1, 8), v2c.Counter32()).setMaxAccess('readonly'),
    dot11AckFailureCount=MibTableColumn((1, 2, 840, 10036, 2, 2, 1, 9), v2c.Counter32()).setMaxAccess('readonly'),
    dot11ReceivedFragmentCount=MibTableColumn((1, 2, 840, 10036, 2, 2, 1, 10), v2c.Counter32()).setMaxAccess('readonly'),
    dot11GroupReceivedFrameCount=MibTableColumn((1, 2, 840, 10036, 2, 2, 1, 11), v2c.Counter32()).setMaxAccess('readonly'),
    dot11FCSErrorCount=MibTableColumn((1, 2, 840, 10036, 2, 2, 1, 12), v2c.Counter32()).setMaxAccess('readonly'),
    dot11TransmittedFrameCount=MibTableColumn((1, 2, 840, 10036, 2, 2, 1, 13), v2c.Counter32()).setMaxAccess('readonly'),
    dot11WEPUndecryptableCount=MibTableColumn((1, 2, 840, 10036, 2, 2, 1, 14), v2c.Counter32()).setMaxAccess('readonly')
)

(ifEntry,
 ifIndex,
 ifDescr
 ) = mibBuilder.importSymbols(
    'IF-MIB',
    'ifEntry',
    'ifIndex',
    'ifDescr'
)

(dot11CountersEntry,
 dot11TransmittedFragmentCount,
 dot11GroupTransmittedFrameCount,
 dot11FailedCount,
 dot11RetryCount,
 dot11MultipleRetryCount,
 dot11FrameDuplicateCount,
 dot11RTSSuccessCount,
 dot11RTSFailureCount,
 dot11AckFailureCount,
 dot11ReceivedFragmentCount,
 dot11GroupReceivedFrameCount,
 dot11FCSErrorCount,
 dot11TransmittedFrameCount,
 dot11WEPUndecryptableCount

 ) = mibBuilder.importSymbols(
    'IEEE802dot11-MIB',
    'dot11CountersEntry',
    'dot11TransmittedFragmentCount',
    'dot11GroupTransmittedFrameCount',
    'dot11FailedCount',
    'dot11RetryCount',
    'dot11MultipleRetryCount',
    'dot11FrameDuplicateCount',
    'dot11RTSSuccessCount',
    'dot11RTSFailureCount',
    'dot11AckFailureCount',
    'dot11ReceivedFragmentCount',
    'dot11GroupReceivedFrameCount',
    'dot11FCSErrorCount',
    'dot11TransmittedFrameCount',
    'dot11WEPUndecryptableCount'
)


rowInstanceId = (1,)
mibInstrumentation = snmpContext.getMibInstrum()
mibInstrumentation.writeVars(
    ((ifIndex.name + rowInstanceId, 1),
     (ifDescr.name + rowInstanceId, 'wifi0'))

)

rowInstanceId = (1,)
mibInstrumentation = snmpContext.getMibInstrum()
mibInstrumentation.writeVars(
    ((dot11TransmittedFragmentCount.name + rowInstanceId, 123),
     (dot11GroupTransmittedFrameCount.name + rowInstanceId, 123456),
     (dot11FailedCount.name + rowInstanceId, 1350),
     (dot11RetryCount.name + rowInstanceId, 1251),
     (dot11MultipleRetryCount.name + rowInstanceId, 234),
     (dot11FrameDuplicateCount.name + rowInstanceId, 566),
     (dot11RTSSuccessCount.name + rowInstanceId, 867),
     (dot11RTSFailureCount.name + rowInstanceId, 231),
     (dot11AckFailureCount.name + rowInstanceId, 856),
     (dot11ReceivedFragmentCount.name + rowInstanceId, 568),
     (dot11GroupReceivedFrameCount.name + rowInstanceId, 34568),
     (dot11FCSErrorCount.name + rowInstanceId, 345),
     (dot11TransmittedFrameCount.name + rowInstanceId, 78567),
     (dot11WEPUndecryptableCount.name + rowInstanceId, 4545))
)

# Register SNMP Applications at the SNMP engine for particular SNMP context
cmdrsp.GetCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)
cmdrsp.SetCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)
cmdrsp.NextCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)
cmdrsp.BulkCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)

# Register an imaginary never-ending job to keep I/O dispatcher running forever
snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)

# Run I/O dispatcher which would receive queries and send responses
try:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
except:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
    raise
```